# tf.keras loss from two images in serial

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I want to use the stability training approach of [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.04326.pdf) and apply it to a very simple CNN.
The principle architecture is given by:

[image: Figure 1]
As shown in the figure you compute the loss based on the output *f(I)* for the input image *I* and on
the output *f(I')* for the perturbed image *I'*.
My question would be how to do this in a valid way without having two instances of the DNN,
as I'm training on large 3D images. In other words: how can I process two images in serial and compute the loss based on those two images?
I'm using tf2 with keras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can first write your DNN as a `tf.keras` Model.
2. After that, you can write another model which takes two image inputs, applies some Gaussian noise to one, passes them to DNN.
3. Design a custom loss function which finds the proper loss from the two outputs.

Here's a demo code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Add, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random


from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Input, GaussianNoise, BatchNormalization

# shared DNN, this is the base model with a feature-space output, there is only once instance of the model
ip = Input(shape=(32,32,1)) # same as original inputs
f0 = Flatten()(ip)
d0 = Dense(10)(f0) # 10 dimensional feature embedding
dnn = Model(ip, d0)

# final model with two version of images and loss

input_1 = Input(shape=(32,32,1))
input_2 = Input(shape=(32,32,1))

g0 = GaussianNoise(0.5)(input_2)  # only input_2 passes through gaussian noise layer, you can design your own custom layer too

# passing the two images to same DNN

path1 = dnn(input_1) # no noise
path2 = dnn(g0) # noise

model = Model([input_1, input_2], [path1, path2])

def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  # calculate your loss based on your two outputs path1, path2
  pass

model.compile('adam', my_loss)
model.summary()
```

Comment: Thanks!
Only had to concatenate [path1, path2] to use as model output, otherwise I weren't able to use both outputs in the same loss function.